# RequireJS - jQuery is undefined when certain alias is given

Tags: jquery, requirejs

When setting the path for jQuery, whenever I am using:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jQuery': './libs/jquery-1.8.0.min'
    }
});
```

Then:

```
define(['jQuery'], function($) {
    console.log($);
};
```

`$` is gonna be undefined.

However if I am using:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': './libs/jquery-1.8.0.min'
    }
});
```

Then:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    console.log($);
};
```

Everything is working great all in a sudden.

What's the issue with defining jQuery's alias with `jQuery`?

Comment: I wish I had found this question 2 hours ago...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was discussed more over here: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/435