# Dependency is undefined - RequireJS

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to use OpenLayers library with RequireJS.

The problem is, OpenLayers keeps being "undefined" even though it's listed as the only dependency for my module:

```
define(['OpenLayers'],function (OpenLayers) {
   console.log(OpenLayers);
});
```

this will print "undefined".

If I substitute the OpenLayers with jquery (both .js files are in the same folder), it will not be undefined any more.

So why is OpenLayers not loaded by RequireJS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        OpenLayers: {
            exports: 'OpenLayers'
        }
    }
});

require(['OpenLayers'], function(OpenLayers) {
    console.log(OpenLayers);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! However, I'd still like to know why is that required. I though shim was used for libraries that needed other dependencies, but OpenLayers needs none.

Comment: I have no idea.  I am pretty new to require.js.  But it would be nice to know, so I will investigate further.

Comment: I have no idea why, but the OpenLayers.js library attaches itself to the global namespace, both with and without the shim config.  With shim config.

Comment: See this for a possible explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121367/requirejs-jquery-is-undefined-when-certain-alias-is-given

Comment: worked for me when downloading the Openlayers zip package. Did someone manage to get it working with bower as well?? Should be the same, but didn't find an OpenLayers.debug.js there...

Comment: An explanation: [Requirejs why and when to use shim config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28096524/2279924)

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem with Backbone.Marionette. Adding `'marionette': { exports: 'Marionette' }` to the `shim` object worked.

This `shim` addition works with both OpenLayers and Marionette for the following reason (from the [RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)):

> shim: Configure the dependencies and exports for older, traditional "browser globals" scripts **that do not use define()** to declare the dependencies and set a module value. Example (RequireJS 2.1.0+):

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
            //backbone.js
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
            //module value.
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
```

Comment: You are my savior! ;)