# Difference between LazyLoad.js and require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jquery-lazyload

I am currently writing a example application with require.js and now found LazyLoad.js.

Require.js

```
require(["modul1", "modul2"],function(Modul1, Modul2){
```

LazyLoad.js

```
LazyLoad.js(["modul1", "modul2"],function(Modul1, Modul2){
```

Where is the difference between these both?

For me it is important to be able to load modules async and the dependency management should be done automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want automatic dependency management then LazyLoad is not appropriate. LazyLoad is appropriate if you just need a runtime loader and don't care about:

1. Defining [modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)
2. Tracking dependencies. From the [lazyload github](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/) (emphasis mine):

> Use LazyLoad when you need a small, fast, safe dynamic JS or CSS loader, but don't need the overhead of **dependency management** or other extra functionality that larger script loaders provide.
>
> An option for build-time [optimization](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)
>
> It looks like LazyLoad just directly loads URLs and doesn't check for path mappings or if that module is already loaded. So I think your 2nd code snippet would probably look like this:

```
LazyLoad.js(["some/path/modul1.js", "some/path/modul2.js"],function(Modul1, Modul2){
```

Whereas RequireJS would let you do something like this:

```
   require.config({
       paths: {
           modul1: 'libs/module1/blah.1.3.3-min',
           modul2: 'libs/module2/foo.2.7.2-min',
       }
   });

   require(["modul1", "modul2"],function(Modul1, Modul2){
```

And also define [shims](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for what files need to be loaded before these modules.

Comment: So with shim i am able to make an external lib available for require?

Comment: @Androidewbie Yes, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471088/requirejs-why-and-when-to-use-shim-config)