# Shim - how to load files that contains dots

Tags: javascript, requirejs

As in the topic. My file structure is:

```
js/ 
 |- bootstrap
 |   |- module1
 |   |- module2
 |
 |- jquery.min.js
 |- main.js
```

and my main.js file is

```
requirejs.config({

    paths: {
        dropdowns : 'bootstrap/module1'
        ,fixes : 'bootstrap/module1'
    }
    ,shim: {
        'jquery.min' : ['jquery']
    }
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'dropdowns', 'fixes'], function ( $, Dropdowns, Fixes ) {

    console.log( $ );
    var fixes = new Fixes();

});
```

now... it throws the following error in the console:

```
GET http://myurl/myapp/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
```

as we can see it looses the dot with shim. My question is "how to load a file like 'jquery.min.js' where are dots before .js part?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply trying to say "when requesting 'jquery' module, load it from 'jquery.min.js'", then your configuration should look like this:

requirejs.config({

```
paths: {
    dropdowns : 'bootstrap/module1'
    ,fixes : 'bootstrap/module1'
    ,jquery: 'jquery.min'
}
```

});

The shim part would come into play if you need to say that your **other** modules require jquery:

```
shim: {
    dropdowns: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    fixes_validate: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
```

See also this answer for more detail on `shim`: [Requirejs why and when to use shim config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471088/requirejs-why-and-when-to-use-shim-config/15486691#15486691)

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how you load a file called jquery.min. This line is saying jquery.min depends on jquery, which doesn't make too much sense.

```
    'jquery.min' : ['jquery']
```

As jQuery defines an AMD module you should try this instead to specify the path

```
requirejs.config({

    paths: {
        dropdowns : 'bootstrap/module1'
        ,fixes : 'bootstrap/module1'
        ,jquery: 'jquery.min'
   }
});
```

This might give a clearer explanation http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html