# Using jquery with requirejs

Tags: jquery, requirejs, bootbox

I have two javascript libraries, one in which I wrote as a connector and the other being a thirdparty library "bootbox.js". I'm using requirejs to setup my custom library, however I'm not sure how to do the same for bootbox.js without having to alter the bootbox js code.

the **js error** I'm getting.

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Current config.

**warnings.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    "shim": {
        'bootbox': {
            deps: ['./jquery']
        }
    }
});

define(["./jquery", "./vendor/bootbox"], function($) {

    var int;

    int = function(spec) {
        $('#' + spec.id).dialog({do something});
    }

    return int;
}
```

and now **bootbox.js**

```
window.bootbox = window.bootbox || (function init($, undefined) {
  "use strict";
    //do something
}(window.jQuery));
```

Anybody know how to get the bootbox js library to use the jquery namespace?

Comment: have you tried this? http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#shimconfig See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471088/requirejs-why-and-when-to-use-shim-config/15486691#15486691

Comment: I tried requirejs.config({
    "shim": {
        "./vendor/bootbox": ["jquery"]
    }
}); but I'm just really confused with how it works. I'll try reading that article again.

Comment: if you are unable to get it working, please also post your require.config section

Comment: @explunit requirejs is configured by the Tapestry5 framework. I'm doing nothing more than calling the warnings script.

Answer (score 0):

in the `app.js` file

```
require.config({
    ....
    shim: {
        'bootbox': {
            deps: ['./jquery'] --> dependancies 
        }
    }
)}
```

this means that when you

```
require('bootbox')
```

then require.js will bring jquery first and then load your other file .
please visit [this link](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for more info

Comment: Just be very careful if you load jquery from a CDN if you do this. See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim and look at the "Important Optimizer Notes for Shim Config"

Comment: thanks i will take a look at that  .. because im doing this all the time :(

Comment: I was, too. I cannot remember how I resolved it, been more server-side for the last while and only coming back to client now.

Comment: @HusseinNazzal Should I be wrapping shim in requirejs.config? also, what is depts? Thanks.

Comment: @HusseinNazzal still no luck :/, I'm still getting the following error. TypeError: $ is not a function
 

var appendTo = $("body");  I'm doing the following, warnings.js requirejs.config({
    "shim": {
        'bootbox': {
            deps: ['./jquery']
        }
    }
});

define(["./jquery", "./vendor/bootbox"], function($) { and I'm not adding any code to bootbox.

Comment: I believe I'm doing everything as you have specified? Is this a namespace issue?

Comment: i guess you mean `require(["./jquery", "./vendor/bootbox"]` not define

Comment: I just changed my question above to reflect the current code configuration. The error happens from within the bootbox.