# Calling function of non amd in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, shim

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471088/requirejs-why-and-when-to-use-shim-config) & I want to understand this concept more clearly so I have created my two files

`lorem.js`:

```
var lorem = {};

lorem.fun1 = function(){
    console.log('aaa');
};
```

`ipsum.js`:

```
var ipsum = {};
ipsum.color = 'a';

ipsum.fun1 = function(){
    lorem.fun1();
};
```

Ipsum depends on lorem. In the shim configuration I have done something like this:

```
// Filename: main.js

// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
// There usage will become more apparent further along in the tutorial.
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        /*jquery: [
            // 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min' ,
            'libs/jquery/jquery'
        ],
        backbone:[
            'libs/backbone/backbone'
        ],
        underscore:[
            'libs/underscore/underscore'
        ],*/
        ipsum: 'nonamd/ipsum',
        lorem: 'nonamd/lorem'
    },
    shim : {
        /*jquery : {
            exports : 'jQuery'
        },
        underscore : {
            exports : '_'
        },
        backbone : {
            deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports : 'Backbone'
        },*/
        ipsum : {
            deps : ['lorem'],
            exports : 'Ipsum'
        }
    }

});

require(['ipsum'],function (Ipsum) {
    console.log(Ipsum);
});
```

However, `console.log(Ipsum)` prints `undefined` in console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in the shim configuration.

```
  ipsum : {
            deps : ['lorem'],
            exports : 'Ipsum'
        }
```

should be

```
  ipsum : {
            deps : ['lorem'],
            exports : 'ipsum'
        }
```

Note the case change from `'Ipsum'` to `'ipsum'`.

`ipsum` should be a global variable in `ipsum.js`.

In Javascript, variable names are case sensitive, so `ipsum` and `Ipsum` are different. Because you hadn't defined `Ipsum`, only `ipsum`, printing it printed `undefined`.